# Multicolumn Textboxes

Tags: vb.net, textbox, multiple-columns

In most word processing programs there is a multicolumn option that allows text to overflow from one column into the next.  Is there any way to do this using two multiline textboxes or richtextboxes in vb.net?

I have a form that will display a varying amount of data in a textbox, anywhere from 1 to 250 lines.  Right now the user can scroll, but I would like to allow the user the option to expand the size of the form, and if the form is wide enough, spill over into a second column to reduce the overall height of the form/reduce the need to scroll.

Comment: Something like datagridview with no header ?